# Spring Junit testing with h2 - Table not found

Tags: java, sql, spring, h2

I am trying to test one of my services and it suddenly fails with the following exception.

I am trying to figure out what is causing this exception to be thrown:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "XYZ" not found; SQL statement:
insert into xyz (id, xx_id, yy_id, order, path, place_id, primary) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [42102-183]
```

Connection:

```
 Creating new JDBC Driver Connection to [jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false]
```

PersistenceContext used for testing:

```
@Configuration
public class PersistenceContext {

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedDatabase dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .addScript("classpath:sql/db-schema.sql")
                .build();
    }

}
```

db-schema.sql

```
CREATE TABLE xyz(
  id int(11) NOT NULL,
  xx_id int(11) NULL,
  yy_id int(11) NULL,
  path varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  date_time_added datetime NOT NULL,
  "order" int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  "primary" bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_xx FOREIGN KEY (xx_id) REFERENCES xx (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_yy FOREIGN KEY (yy_id) REFERENCES yy (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

The class where the error is thrown

```
private Image addXyzForXX(MultipartFile file, Xx xx) throws ... {
    String destDir = resourceService.getPlacesUploadDir();
    Xyz xyz = new Xyz();

    xyz.setXx(xx);

    String filePath = imageUploadService.upload(file, destDir);

    java.util.Date dt = new java.util.Date();

    java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    String currentTime = sdf.format(dt);

    xyz.setPath(filePath);
    xyz.setDateTimeAdded(currentTime);

    xyz.setOrder(1);
    xyz.setPrimary(true);

    xyz = xyzRepository.save(xyz);
    return xyz;
}
```

Xyz Repository

```
@Repository
public interface XyzRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Xyz, Long> {

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "xyz")
public class Xyz{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String path;
    private String dateTimeAdded;
    private Integer order;
    private Boolean primary;

    @ManyToOne(optional=true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "xxId")
    private Xx xx;

    [getters and setters for each field]
}
```

The testing class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
public class ImageServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    private XyzService xyzService;
    @Autowired
    private XxService xxService;
    @Test
    public void testArgumentsNullity3() throws Exception {
        XX xx = new XX("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
        xx= xxService.addXx(xx);
        xyzService.addImage(XxService.Scope.XX, xx,new MockMultipartFile("a","a","image/jpeg", new byte[1024]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the test class that is generating the error?

Comment: @willOEM I updated my initial comment

Comment: You are still not showing the actual test class.  I suspect that your test context is not properly configuring your database.

Answer (score 2):

I found the actual problem.

The exception message I showed in my initial post is missing something important. In the stacktrace there was something else that says "bad sql grammar". I was focused on "images" table because this was the first thing in the stack trace.

After I checked all the possible known issues, I tried to rename the fields from my entity because I thought it will H2 will interpret them as keywords.

After renaming the fields, everything worked just fine.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!